# Powershell Remoting Speeding up a Foreach Loop Hosted Exchange

Tags: powershell, foreach, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I have a CSV of email adddresses and Departments that I need to set on Live@edu.  The command I currently have looks something like this:

```
Import-CSV departments.csv | ForEach-Object { Set-User $_.EmailAddress $_.Department }`
```

The problem is, this operation takes FOREVER.

My first thought is that it would be great to have the `ForEach-Object` command actually be forwarded over to the remote machine, so that it will only need to create the one pipeline between the two machines, but when I go into the PSSession, there doesn't seem to be any `foreach-object` available.  For reference, How I Import the PSSession is:

```
Import-PSSession(New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
    -ConnectionUri 'https://ps.outlook.com/powershell' `
    -Credential (Get-Credential) `
    -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection)
```

Is there a better way that I can import the session to allow ForEach-Object to be remote, or to import an aliased version of the remote foreach-object, perhaps as ForEach-Object-Remote, or perhaps does anybody have something better to suggest to streamline this process?

UPDATE:
A Couple Things I've tried:

1. Using the `-AsJob` switch on the implicitly remoted command.

   ```
   Import-CSV departments.csv | ForEach-Object { Set-User $_.EmailAddress $_.Department -AsJob }
   ```

   This, unfortunately, doesn't work because there are throttling limits in place that don't allow the additional connections.  Worse than that, I don't even know that anything went wrong until I check the results, and find that very few of them actually got changed.
2. Importing the `ForEach-Object` under a different name.

   Turns out that adding a prefix is easy as putting `-Prefix RS` in the `Import-PSSession` Command to have things like the ForEach-Object from the Remote Session become `ForEach-RSObject` in the local session.  Unfortunately, this won't work for me, because the server I'm connecting to does not does not have the `Microsoft.Powershell` ConfigurationName available to me.

UPDATE 2: The Set-User cmdlet seems to be Microsoft provided for Live@edu administration.  Its purpose is to set User attributes.  It is not a script or cmdlet that I am able to debug.  It doesn't take pipeline input, unfortunately, so that would not be able to fix the issue.

As Far as I can tell, the problem is that it has to construct and tear down a pipeline to the remote machine every time this command runs, rather than being able to reuse it.  The remote ForEach idea would have allowed me to offload that loop to avoid having to create all those remote pipelines, while the -asJob would have allowed them to all run in parallel.  However, it also caused errors to fail silently, and only a few of the records actually get properly updated.

I suspect at this point that I will not be able to speed up this command, but will have to do whatever I can to limit the amount of data that needs to be changed in a particular run by keeping better track of what I have done before (keeping differential snapshots).  Makes the job a bit harder.

EDIT: **Start-Automate** left a very useful help, unfortunately, neither of them work.  It is my feeling at this point that I won't find a way to speed this up until my provider gives access to more powershell cmdlets, or the exchange cmdlets are modified to allow multiple pipelines, neither of which I expect to happen any time soon.  I am marking his answer as correct, despite the ultimate result that nothing helps significantly.  Thanks, **Start-Automate**.

Comment: It would help if you could specify more in detail what's taking "forever". What does `Set-User`do? If it doesn't produce any output, it's hard to tell where this lags. I'd put in a few `Write-Debug` to get a better view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed up your script and also avoid trying to make two connections to the server by the use of the foreach statement, instead of Foreach-Object.

```
$departments = @(import-csv .\departments.csv)

foreach ($user in $departments) {
    Set-User $user.EmailAddress $user.Department 
}
```

If you need to batch, you could use the for statement, moving forward in each batch

```
for ($i =0; $i -lt $departments.Count; $i+=3) {
     $jobs = @()
     $jobs+= Invoke-Command { Set-User $departments[$i].EmailAddress $departments[$i].Department } -AsJob
     $jobs+= Invoke-Command { Set-User $departments[$i + 1].EmailAddress $departments[$i + 1].Department } -AsJob
     $jobs+= Invoke-Command { Set-User $departments[$i + 2].EmailAddress $departments[$i + 2].Department } -AsJob
     $jobs | Wait-job | Receive-job
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The difference between foreach and Forach-Object is that the latter uses the pipeline, which in turn has performance effects. Ref: [Posholic](http://poshoholic.com/2007/08/21/essential-powershell-understanding-foreach/) and [BSonPoSH](http://bsonposh.com/archives/327)

Comment: Still testing the second idea, but I don't see how using the foreach loop instead of foreach-object will avoid or streamline connections to the server, as the only command remoted would in either case be the Set-User command.

Comment: Overall, two great ideas, but neither will actually perform significantly better.  I am very limited in the subset of powershell I can get from exchange, and the Exchange Management Console Powershell Cmdlets are very limited in dealing with remote pipelines.  The first **does** work, although for my purpose it may be better overall to ignore the slightly longer time it will take to use foreach-object to gain the memory management of the pipeline.  The second one won't work on any remote Exchange server because the Exchange commands don't allow multiple pipelines.

Comment: You can get around the concurrency by simply using Invoke-Command and creating several connections with New-PSSession.  As far as I recall, Exchange has a limit of 3 inbound connections at once.